# Reading table content of an external HTML file using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an external HTML file "mainstatus.htm" containing some tables. I load the file content into a div with the id "result" using the jQuery .load() function. Now I want see if some TDs in the second table inside the main table is holding a specific data. But it seems that I am not able to access the content of the loaded file using the way I have done bellow.

```
$('#result').load('http://localhost/mainstatus.htm', function() {
});
alert($("#result table:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)").val());
```

This alerts "Undifined"! Whcat point am I missing or what is even the correct approch?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your alert inside your callback

```
$('#result').load('http://localhost/mainstatus.htm', function() {
  alert($("#result table:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)").text());
});
```

As load is asynchronous, your alert was executed before your data is even loaded,You need to wait for the data to be loaded  before you can use it,that is why a callback function is there.

One more thing :  You were using `.val()` to get content of `td`, you need to use `.text()` or `.html()`

Comment: I did this at the first time and this is not the issue!

Comment: @RezaSaberi, No, that is an issue,(_you should read [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/load/)_), and see the update in my answer, you are using `.val()`, you need to use `.text()` instead